# Storing JSON in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I m trying to store some data in MongoDB, I am not sure of the type of data that I am being provided with as I am getting it from a formbuilder(https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder) that I am using.

I am getting the data from:

```
  document.getElementById('getJSON').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var ans = formBuilder.actions.getData('json', true);

  //console.log(ans);
  //var ans2 = JSON.parse(ans);

  alert(ans);

  console.log(ans);

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: ans,
        url: "/j",
        success: function(){
            console.log('success');
        }
    });

    document.forms["myForm"].submit();

});
```

It reaches my back end as so:

```
//FETCHING THE JSON OF THE CLAUSE FORM CREATED BY THE ADMIN
router.post('/j', function(req, res, next) {

req.session.fdata = req.body; //JSON FETCHED FROM JAVASCRIPT USING AJAX, STORED IN SESSION


if(req.session.fdata==null) //CHECKING IF WE ARE RECEIVING VALUES
{
    res.redirect('/admin');
}
else {

    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {

        assert.equal(null, err);

        //var jfdata = JSON.parse(req.session.fdata);

        db.collection('clauses').insertOne(req.session.fdata, function (err, result) {

            console.log('New Clause Added');
            console.log(req.session.fdata);
            db.close();

        });
    });

    res.redirect('/admin');
}
});
```

I insert it into the DB and it looks fine in the DB but on retrieval I cant seem to access the inner portions of the data. Is my data in the wrong format? Is it JSON or a JS object?

it looks like so in the DB:(the db is empty before insertion)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH2W4.png)

This is what the console prints

```
 [ { _id: 596de520ef77eb2614cd1e47,
 '[\n\t{\n\t\t"type": "number",\n\t\t"label": "Number",\n\t\t"description": 
 "total number",\n\t\t"placeholder": "0",\n\t\t"className": "form-
 control",\n\t\t"name": "number-1500374279764"\n\t}\n]': '' },
 { _id: 596de520ef77eb2614cd1e48 } ]
```

Comment: We will need to see your db structure or data that you are saving to know what is wrong. How do you know it looks fine in db?

Comment: console `req.session.fdata` and put that in your question.

Comment: on the console it is the same,except that the new lines are represented by \n and \t for new lines and tabs respectively.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your data. It is not a proper JSON I guess.

Comment: In the first object from your console, _id is fine. But the array you have to assign to some field.

Comment: I concur with your conclusion, thanks. Any material which i could refer to?

Comment: when inserting data into mongo which is in JSON form do i need to store the data in a separate file and then import it? Cause i think whats happening here is that the JSON data is inserted as a string and not as separate fields.

Comment: You have to format it before saving to db.

Answer (score 2):

The data you are trying to save does not seem right to me.

What you are getting is a string of the JSON object.
You have to use `JSON.parse` to convert it to a proper JSON object.

```
JSON.parse('[\n\t{\n\t\t"type": "number",\n\t\t"label":"Number",\n\t\t"description": "total number",\n\t\t"placeholder": "0",\n\t\t"className": "form-control",\n\t\t"name": "number-1500374279764"\n\t}\n]')
```

After that, you can form the data and insert in DB.

```
var query = {
             array : [{"type": "number",
                    "label": "Number",
                    "description": "total number",
                    "placeholder": "0",
                    "className": "form-control",
                    "name": "number - 1500374279764"}]
        }

db.collection('clauses').insertOne(query, function (err, result) 
{
        db.close();
});
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I would say it probably will not help considering the syntax is completely invalid. Also does not even seem to bother addressing the issue of taking the form data and inserting it. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Shrabanee thank you for your answer, it threw a unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 error

Comment: JSON.parse() you have to use for the JSON string. Not the whole thing that you are getting.

Comment: so when i get my data in javascript I should stringify it then parse it? Sorry if it feels like you need to spell out everything for me I ma very new to this, I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Please look into JSON.parse docs for more info on how to use it. Here in SO we will just help you and guide if you are wrong somewhere. We can not write down each and every code for you. Please try to put some effort to understand the data you are getting to save.

Comment: I have edited my answer with some code to help you. But it is not full proof.

Comment: Try to solve and let us know if you are facing some issue.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by including the contentType parameter in the AJAX call. That resulted in my data being formatted in the correct JSON form. I sincerely appreciate the help provided by all.

Comment: Glad to hear that.. :)